Scaling text in SVG
I'm trying to understand text scaling in SVG.
In here


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->

<svg
   width="59.018078mm"
   height="80.593658mm"
   viewBox="0 0 59.018078 80.593658"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg1"
   inkscape:version="1.3.2 (1:1.3.2+202311252150+091e20ef0f)"
   sodipodi:docname="scale_check.svg"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <sodipodi:namedview
 id="namedview1"
 pagecolor="#ffffff"
 bordercolor="#666666"
 borderopacity="1.0"
 inkscape:showpageshadow="2"
 inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
 inkscape:pagecheckerboard="0"
 inkscape:deskcolor="#d1d1d1"
 inkscape:document-units="mm"
 inkscape:zoom="0.91537085"
 inkscape:cx="56.807577"
 inkscape:cy="222.86049"
 inkscape:window-width="1862"
 inkscape:window-height="1016"
 inkscape:window-x="58"
 inkscape:window-y="27"
 inkscape:window-maximized="1"
 inkscape:current-layer="layer1"
 showgrid="false" />
  <defs
 id="defs1" />
  <style
 id="style1">
text { font-size:6px;line-height:1.25;font-family:sans-serif;-inkscape-font-specification:'sans-serif, Normal';stroke-width:0;stroke:none }
  </style>
  <g
 inkscape:label="Layer 1"
 inkscape:groupmode="layer"
 id="layer1"
 transform="translate(-1.322437,-0.79811096)">
<text
   xml:space="preserve"
   x="9.4902344"
   y="45"
   id="text_manual"><tspan
     sodipodi:role="line"
     id="tspan2"
     x="9.4902344"
     y="45">original text</tspan></text>
<rect
   style="fill:#a400ff"
   id="rect3"
   width="4"
   height="4"
   x="10"
   y="10" />
<rect
   style="fill:#a40000;stroke:none"
   id="rect1"
   width="4"
   height="4"
   x="10"
   y="10"
   transform="scale(1,2)" />
<text
   xml:space="preserve"
   x="13.429504"
   y="46.268539"
   id="text3"
   transform="scale(0.70710677,1.4142136)"><tspan
     sodipodi:role="line"
     id="tspan3"
     x="13.429504"
     y="46.268539"
     style="stroke-width:0">scaled text</tspan></text>
  </g>
</svg>
 



The rectangles are scaled 200% on the y-axis and they double in height, as expected.
However the text - that also doubles in height -  is scaled by sqrt(2) on the y-axis and by half that on the x-axis.
What's the reason for that?
Is that because the scaling then also applies to the inner tspan and therefore gets squared? and why does the x-coordinate also get scaled, though visually the two texts are aligned left?
Here's the image for reference:


What makes you think that the scaled text is twice the height of the original text? What rendering engine is producing the scaled text? It seems far too wide. Have you tried Firefox?

You applied scale(0.70710677,1.4142136) to the parent <text> element so the <tspan> is also affected by this transform. Please clarify what should be the expected result.

OP is saying that the scaled text is actually a 2,1 scaling (it really is, I did a pixel check) - so why is the text transform showing (0.707, 1.41)
